# DB2 to Oracle SQL Conversion - OPTIMIZE FOR 20 ROWS;

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

In DB2, I have a sql for instance:

```
SELECT LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,EMPNO,SALARY
  FROM EMP
  ORDER BY SALARY DESC
  OPTIMIZE FOR 20 ROWS;
```

If it is converted to SQL for Oracle, how should it be?

I am thinking of this but I am not sure if it is correct or not:

```
  SELECT  /*+ FIRST_ROWS(20) */  LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,EMPNO,SALARY
  FROM EMP
  ORDER BY SALARY DESC
```

Comment: ORDER BY SALARY DESC FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY, if newer Oracle version.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE FOR 20 ROWS` optimizes the access plan to deliver that said 20 rows faster, but still returns all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct: use the first_rows(n) hint.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/hintsref.htm#CHDFIAJD

Comment: Do I really need to specify First_rows(n) in oracle for optimization purpose?

Comment: It depends on what problem you're trying to solve. Maybe for the purpose of a user interface or tool that is consuming the result you want to get the first rows back faster to give a better user experience. Typically you might face a choice between having all of the rows returned over a long time (e.g. 30 seconds), but getting the first ones back quickly, vs getting no rows back for a while and then all of them at once (e.g. after 10 seconds). It is sometimes used as a shortcut to promote index usage, though there are better ways.

Comment: If my purpose is to fetch only top 20 rows with fastest path, should I use first_row or rownum?

Comment: You should use "fetch first 20 rows { ONLY | WITH TIES }" in 12c and above, or ROWNUM <= n in 11g and below. FIRST_ROWS(n) shouldn't be required with ROWNUM <= n, but this may be version dependent. More info here: https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/what-is-the-difference-between-the-first_rows-hint-and-rownum-in-the-where-clause/