# DB2 Optimize for n rows

Tags: db2

I'm learning DB2, and I came across this clause: `OPTIMIZE FOR 1 ROW` right after `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY`.

I understand that `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY` would give me the first 100 rows that qualified. But I don't understand what the `OPTIMIZE FOR 1 ROW` really doing here. I read [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statement-optimizing-retrieval-small-set-rows) DB2 documentation, it says

> Use OPTIMIZE FOR 1 ROW clause to influence the access path. OPTIMIZE FOR 1 ROW tells Db2 to select an access path that returns the first qualifying row quickly.

and [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=statement-optimize-clause) DB2 documentation, it says

> In general, if you are retrieving only a few rows, specify OPTIMIZE FOR 1 ROW to influence the access path that Db2 selects.

But I'm still confused. Is using `OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS` would make a query more efficient?

I also found [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007335/db2-to-oracle-sql-conversion-optimize-for-20-rows) and it seems like `OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS` is equivalent to `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` per the accepted answer.

But when I experimented it myself using `OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS` instead of `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`, the result set was not the same. With `OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS`, the query returns all qualifying rows.

Could someone please explain it to me what `OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS` really does? Thanks!

Comment: The documentation text is correct " ...to select an access path that returns the first qualifying row quickly."  It is just a hint to the optimizer . It is __different__ from the functional requirement to return `fetch first n rows only`.  If you get to learn the output of `db2exfmt` or visual-explain to interpret the access plan, you may see the impact via the operators mentioned in the access plan.

Comment: @mao Thanks for your comment. I haven't learned about the access plan yet. I'll definitely pay close attention when I get there.

Comment: The engine operators can be classified as pipelined or materialized. Pipelined ones won't be affected, but the materialization can be tweaked to return the first block of rows fast. However, in the long run this special optimization can be costly for the entire query.

Answer (score 1):

> Is using `OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS` would make a query more efficient?

Not necessarily. However, it might cause your application to start receiving rows earlier than it otherwise would, if there is an access plan alternative that can find the *first row* matching the query criteria faster although the *entire query* will as a result run longer.

There's this bit in the [Db2 for LUW docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=wss-using-optimize-n-rows-clause-fetch-first-n-rows-only-clause) that gives some examples specific to that platform:

> Try specifying `OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS` along with `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`, to encourage query access plans that return rows directly from the referenced tables, without first performing a buffering operation such as inserting into a temporary table, sorting, or inserting into a hash join hash table.
>
> Applications that specify `OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS` to encourage query access plans that avoid buffering operations, yet retrieve the entire result set, might experience poor performance. This is because the query access plan that returns the first *n* rows fastest might not be the best query access plan if the entire result set is being retrieved.

Comment: "...This is because the query access plan that returns the first n rows fastest might not be the best query access plan if the entire result set is being retrieved..." -- so true.